# Can I activate password feedback on a tty?

Tags: login, password, keyboard, agetty

A few weeks ago, I decided to clean up my keyboard and ended up messing up a few keys as I was snapping them back onto the board. As a result, some characters have become annoyingly difficult to enter... And obviously I use a few of said characters in my password.

I am planning to replace my keyboard of course, but in the meantime, having to go through 4-5 login attempts a day on my ttys is starting to get on my nerves (I don't use a desktop manager).

I've managed to alleviate the issue a bit by setting `pwfeedback` in my `sudo` config. This allows me to "see" whenever my keyboard skips a character. However I couldn't find a similar option for the `agetty` and `login` combo.

Is there a way to activate password feedback for the tty login prompts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, to the source code we go!

`util-linux`'s `login` program is in charge by the time my login prompt appears. Let's start [there](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux), more specifically in the [`login-utils/login.c`](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/27afe5016842c22d256ea9f88b598d637ca0df84/login-utils/login.c) file.

Now, `login` appears to be in charge of the `login` prompt, since it generates it in [`loginpam_get_prompt`](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/27afe5016842c22d256ea9f88b598d637ca0df84/login-utils/login.c#L702) and registers it with PAM in [`init_loginpam`](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/27afe5016842c22d256ea9f88b598d637ca0df84/login-utils/login.c#L740). The [`loginpam_auth`](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/27afe5016842c22d256ea9f88b598d637ca0df84/login-utils/login.c#L751) function then takes over, and control goes to PAM's [`pam_authenticate`](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/27afe5016842c22d256ea9f88b598d637ca0df84/login-utils/login.c#L772) function. This means that `login` merely defines a prompt for the username and that's it.

To PAM then: what we're interested in clearly happens in [`pam_authenticate`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_authenticate) :

> The pam_authenticate function is used to authenticate the user. The user is required to provide an authentication token depending upon the authentication service, usually this is a password, but could also be a finger print.

Now, shadow-based authentication (`/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`) is handled by the `pam_unix` module. My distribution (Arch) provides PAM through the [`pam`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/pam/) package, which means our journey continues over to [linux-pam.org](http://linux-pam.org) and [its source code](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam). [`modules/pam_unix/pam_unix_auth.c`](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/955b3e2f100205be2db4358e9c812de2ae453b8e/modules/pam_unix/pam_unix_auth.c) seems a good place to start. PAM modules provide their authentication mechanism through a `pam_sm_authenticate` function, which we find [here](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/955b3e2f100205be2db4358e9c812de2ae453b8e/modules/pam_unix/pam_unix_auth.c#L97). The password (or "authentication token", see above) is fetched with [a call](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/955b3e2f100205be2db4358e9c812de2ae453b8e/modules/pam_unix/pam_unix_auth.c#L156) to PAM's [`pam_get_authtok`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pam_get_authtok.3.html) function. It is declared in the [`security/pam_ext.h`](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/955b3e2f100205be2db4358e9c812de2ae453b8e/libpam/include/security/pam_ext.h) header file, so that's where we're going next.

```c
extern int PAM_NONNULL((1,3)) 
pam_get_authtok (pam_handle_t *pamh, 
                 int item, 
                 const char **authtok, 
                 const char *prompt);
```

Nothing too promising in those arguments but well... Let's see [the definition](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/955b3e2f100205be2db4358e9c812de2ae453b8e/libpam/pam_get_authtok.c#L78). `pam_unix` passed `NULL` for the `prompt` argument and `PAM_AUTHTOK` for `item`, so we end up [here](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/955b3e2f100205be2db4358e9c812de2ae453b8e/libpam/pam_get_authtok.c#L156). Now that hardcoded `PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_OFF` given to `pam_prompt` just doesn't look good for me...

```c
retval = pam_prompt (pamh, PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_OFF, &resp[0], "%s", PROMPT);
```

By the way, the password `PROMPT` is also hardcoded ([here](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/955b3e2f100205be2db4358e9c812de2ae453b8e/libpam/pam_get_authtok.c#L39)), so there goes my dream of a more exotic password prompt... Anyway, let's go over to the [`pam_prompt`](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/955b3e2f100205be2db4358e9c812de2ae453b8e/libpam/pam_vprompt.c) function. The actual prompt happens [here](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/955b3e2f100205be2db4358e9c812de2ae453b8e/libpam/pam_vprompt.c#L83), where PAM calls a conversation function fetched a few lines [above](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/955b3e2f100205be2db4358e9c812de2ae453b8e/libpam/pam_vprompt.c#L63). A quick look at [the `pam_get_item` and `pam_set_item`](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/955b3e2f100205be2db4358e9c812de2ae453b8e/libpam/pam_item.c) functions introduces us to the [`pam_conv`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_conv) structure defined [here](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/955b3e2f100205be2db4358e9c812de2ae453b8e/libpam/include/security/_pam_types.h#L280).

Now, finding information on the default PAM conversation function was a lot trickier than it should be (I think). Everywhere I looked, the structure remained uninitialised and `pam_unix` does not appear to define its own. However I managed to find the generic [`misc_conv`](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/955b3e2f100205be2db4358e9c812de2ae453b8e/libpam_misc/misc_conv.c#L274) function, which passes `PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_OFF` over to [`read_string`](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/955b3e2f100205be2db4358e9c812de2ae453b8e/libpam_misc/misc_conv.c#L128) and... [here](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/955b3e2f100205be2db4358e9c812de2ae453b8e/libpam_misc/misc_conv.c#L148)'s where PAM deactivates input feedback.

**Conclusion:** the absence of password feedback is hardcoded. Too bad. A little digging got me to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/issues/58) and [this Arch BBS thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=238391). Apparently, [the feature was available](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/19207) back when PAM wasn't a standard for authentication. I guess it makes sense not to have implemented it again - security and all - but you know, an option would have been nice.

Anyway, I've just ordered my new keyboard.

Comment: `login` happens to use the generic `misc_conv`, but it could as well provide a custom conversation function with the functionality you need. It is `login` to blame for not doing it, not `pam`